# reduce a differential equation $y'+\dfrac{x}{y}=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to reduce a differential equation.

$y'+\dfrac{x}{y}=0$

I reduced this. But my answer don't much with [Wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27%2Bx%2Fy%3D0&lang=ja). Please tell me what is wrong.

$y'=-\dfrac{x}{y}=-\dfrac{1}{\left( \dfrac{y}{x}\right) }$
When I put, $u=\dfrac{y}{x}$,

$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=-\dfrac{1}{u}$

differentiate both sides with respect to x

$\dfrac{du}{dx}=-\dfrac{1+u^{2}}{ux}$

$\dfrac{u}{1+u^{2}}\dfrac{du}{dx}=-\dfrac{1}{x}$

Integrate both sides with respect to x

$\dfrac{1}{2}\log \left| u^{2}+1\right| =-\log \left| x\right| +C'$

Organize the formula

$u^{2}+1=\dfrac{C}{x}$

$\begin{aligned}\dfrac{y^{2}}{x}+1=\dfrac{C}{x}\\ y=\pm \sqrt{Cx-x^{2}}\end{aligned}$

Comment: From where does $y = -\frac{1}{\frac{y}{x}}$ come

Comment: Your equation is separable

Comment: Hint: $dy=udx+xdu$

Comment: Why do you let the factor $\frac12$ disappear? Why do you claim $u^2 = \frac{y^2}{x}$ instead of $\frac{y^2}{x^2}$?

Comment: @RobbytheBelgian has it. Fix the two errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure exactly what our OP langhtorn means by "reduction", or how the calculations presented in the text of the question itself work, but here is my solution:

$y' + \dfrac{x}{y} = 0; \tag 1$

multiply through by $y$:

$yy' + x = 0; \tag 2$

$\dfrac{1}{2}(y^2)' + x = 0; \tag 3$

$(y^2)' = -2x; \tag 4$

integrate:

$y^2 = -x^2 + C = C - x^2; \tag 5$

then

$y = \pm \sqrt{C - x^2} = \pm (C - x^2)^{1/2}.  \tag 6$

Check:

$y' = \pm \dfrac{1}{2}(C - x^2)^{-1/2}(-2x) = \pm (-x(C - x^2)^{-1/2})$
$= \pm (-\dfrac{x}{(C - x^2)^{1/2}}) = -\dfrac{x}{\pm (C - x^2)^{1/2}} = -\dfrac{x}{y}. \checkmark \tag 7$

In light of this verified solution, I am skeptical of our OPs calculations, but as of this writing have not scrutinized them carefully enough to find an error.

Comment: Thank you. I think again this question.

Answer (score 1):

you can solve it by separable method as follows:
$$yy'+x=0$$
$$ydy+xdx=0$$
$$\int ydy+\int xdx=C$$
and then complete the solution

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: you are welcome